# Flutter No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() in Flutter and Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

```
void main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
     future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return MaterialApp(
        ........
       );
  }
}
```

> [core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp() See also: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors

then when i use

```
void main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

the error disappears but the the app cant use Firebase Authentication

Comment: How do you determine that the app "can't use Firebase Authentication" in your second snippet? Looks correct to me.

Comment: "the app cant use Firebase Authentication" What does that mean? Is there an error message?

Comment: no, no error message

Comment: when i click the sign_in or sign_up button the app should send data to the fire base (email & password) then if its correct the app show a page that say show ur email + a welcome text. the problem is non of that happen after i used the async method

Answer (score 0):

The `FutureBuilder` widget is used to build a widget given asynchronous computations that return a future, but it doesn't have a `snapshot` parameter to indicate if the future completed successfully, which may cause such an error.

`Firebase.initializeApp()`, should be called before calling the runApp() method. [Ref](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/#initialization)